# Prove that: $(\vec u\times \vec v)\times \vec w =(\vec w \cdot {\vec u}) \vec v - (\vec v \cdot \vec w) \vec u $

Tags: vectors

> Prove that: $(\vec u\times \vec v)\times \vec w =(\vec w \cdot {\vec u}) \vec v - (\vec v \cdot \vec w) \vec u $

I'm trying to solve this question, and my only thoughts of proving it is just to substitute $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and same for all vectors and open it up following the dot and cross product rules. 
But I was wondering if there's another creative way other than the straight forward way that I'm thinking about. 
Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ak. I agree and I have retracted my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "creative" way first notes anything orthogonal to $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{u},\,\vec{v}$. Since $(a\vec{u}\times b\vec{v})\times c\vec{w}=abc(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})\times\vec{w}$, the coefficient of $\vec{u}$ needs to be bilinear in $\vec{v},\,\vec{w}$. Further, it needs to be a scalr invariant under rotations, so it must be a multiple of $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w}$. We can treat the $\vec{v}$ coefficient similarly, making it a multiple of $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{w}$. By $u\leftrightarrow v$-antisymmetry, some $k$ satisfies$$(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})\times\vec{w}=k[(\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u})\vec{v}-(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{w})\vec{u}].$$You can fix $k=1$ with e.g. $\vec{u}=\vec{i},\,\vec{v}=\vec{w}=\vec{j}$ making both sides $-\vec{i}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood some of it, but kinda started losing it when you talked about antisymmetry and trilinearity, if you could explain it a little more that would help me alot

Comment: @Pwaol See edit.

Comment: If you want to do this avoiding coordinates, then you will have to use things like linearity and symmetry.

Comment: Thanks alot, I guess I'm going to stick to coordinates since I feel like this is too high of a level for me, I got the idea though and I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The vector (u x v)xw is perpendicular to uxv , therefore it's in the same plane as the vectors u and v.
Therefore , (u x v)xw can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors u and v because it's coplanar with both the vectors .

Now , let
(u x v)xw = l.u + m.v ,...(1)

where l , m are constants .

Taking scalar product with w both sides ,

0 = l(w.u) + m(w.v)

Solving , we get ,

l/(w.u) = -m/(w.v) = k(say) , where k is a constant .

Therefore , l=k(w.u) and m=-k(w.v)

Putting these values in equation 1 , we get

(u x v)xw= k{(w.u)v - (w.v)u}

And more generally ,

(u x v)xw = (w.u)v -(w.v)u